# How to write a unity script to observe the position of a game object (during scene creation)

Tags: unityscript

I want to write a simple Unity script to be notified when a game object is moved, during the creation of the scene.

More precisly, I want to write a Unity script that can recognize when the user click on the blue, or red, or green axis of the selected game object, and then when the user release the click.

If this is not possible, I want to write a script that can recognize when the selected game object position changes.

Are there existing c# listeners that can be used from within Unity to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update function can be activated during edit time. Here you could detect if the object has moved.

Firstly, you need to tell unity that you want the update function during edit time;
[ExectureInEditMode] attribute. For more information [see here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html).

This will cause the update routine to be called every time something in the scene changed. You will then need to store a "last position" variable in your object and check if the current position is different. If it is, the object moved.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    void Update() {
        if (lastPosition != transform.position)
        {
            // object moved
        }
        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

This will also execute at runtime, so you might want to set a flag to indicate if it's runtime or not. This can be done by setting the flag in the Start() routine.

There is already a flag to indicate this. You can check [Application.isPlaying](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isPlaying.html) or [Application.isEditor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isEditor.html).

Comment: I need Unity pro? The method Update() is never called. I know it because I inserted the line Debug.Log( "called" ); ...

Comment: Make sure you have the attribute on the class. I believe it's called only when something in the scene changes.

Comment: [ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SmartFollow : MonoBehaviour {

 void Update() {

 Debug.Log("Hello"); } }

Comment: Yes the attribute is on the class not on the method.

Comment: Well according to the unity documentation linked this should work. It needs to be attached to an object in the scene and probably the object you want to react to being moved. Apart from that I can't think of anything. It's not "pro-only".

Comment: The problem is that Update() is never called if I write this simple code:

using ... [ExecuteInEditMode] public class SmartFollow : MonoBehaviour { void Update() { Debug.Log("Hello"); } }